# Participle to finite verb

Tags: participles

I have to rewrite the following sentence by changing the participle into a finite verb

> Going up the stairs, the boy fell down.

According to me the answer should be

***While the boy was going up the stairs, he fell down***.

But the answer is

> When he was going up the stairs, the boy fell down.

Are both the sentences same?

Comment: Yes, they are. That is the problem with language exercises which assume that there is only one answer.

Comment: They have a very subtle difference in meaning, but are essentially the same—and both answer the question. (My own version would probably be ***As*** *he was going up the stairs, the boy fell down.*)

Answer (score 2):

Just because someone says something is the "correct" answer doesn't mean that it is the *only* correct answer.  Here's another:

> **As** the boy was going up the stairs, he fell down.

and there are probably many more.

However "while" is not precisely the same as "when".  "While" suggests "during the process of", as an *ongoing* action, and "when" suggests "at a static moment in time".

> **While** the clock **is striking** the hour, we will all jump out and surprise her
>
> **When** the clock **strikes** the hour, we will all jump out and surprise her.